# How to get full screen button in other applications on OS X?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I want the full screen button in image 2 to appear in the app shown in image 1 (Photoshop). In Chrome there's an option to go full screen, but in Photoshop and Office this does not exist. Is there any way to get it?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 3):

Full screen support requires the developer to integrate it in to the app. You can't just 'add' the button to an app.